# Android Studio. How export Live Template to file?

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 2.3.2. 
I want to export **Live Templates-->AndroidLog** to file.
[image]

How I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA (and Android Studio) stores definitions of custom live templatein automatically generated configuration files `<group_name>.xml`.

Depending on the operating system you are using, the `<group_name>.xml` files are stored at the following locations:

- Windows: `<your_user_home_directory>\.AndroidStudio<version_number>\config\templates`
- Linux: `~/.AndroidStudio<version>/config/templates`
- macOS: `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio<version>/templates`

Now you can share the templates among your teammates, send the relevant files to them with the instruction to save the files in the templates folder

**Or** You can sharing live templates through export/import

1. Open the Settings / Preferences Dialog by pressing Ctrl+Alt+S or by choosing File | Settings for Windows and Linux or IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for macOS, and click Live Templates under Editor.
2. On the main menu, choose File | export Settings.
3. In the Export Settings dialog box that opens, select the Live Template check box and specify the name of the .jar file where the exported settings will be stored. When you click OK, IntelliJ IDEA generates a file with the specified named based on the .xml configuration files stored in the templates folder.
4. To share the templates among your teammates, pass the generated .jar file to them with the following instructions:
5. Save the received .jar file on your computer.
6. Choose File | Import Settings on the main menu and and specify the location of the received .jar file.
7. In the Select Components to Import dialog box that opens, select the Live Templates check box and click OK.

For any other information, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/sharing-live-templates.html) the official IntelliJ guide

Comment: Thank you.  It works great.  I just copied folder templates to a new computer after installing Android Studio on it.  Restarting AS is needed.

Answer (score 10):

### Updated >Android 4.1

> IDE configuration directory changes The locations of user
> configuration directories have been changed to the following:
>
> Windows Syntax: %APPDATA%\Google<product>
>
> Example: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1
>
> macOS Syntax: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/
>
> Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
>
> Linux Syntax: ~/.config/Google/
>
> Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

**C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\templates**

Answer (score 2):

For Mac:
Android 4.1
/Users/{User Name}/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/templates

Answer (score 0):

Update about the last version of Android Studio.
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

To export the settings (or only the Live Templates) use:

File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Export Settings

Select Live Templates and select the folder where to save the file

[image]

[image]