# Where are Live Templates stored in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I am looking for the location of where the Live Templates are stored in Android Studio in Windows.

I looked at previous answers where the locations is under:
.\config folder but in my case there is no "templates" folder that I can look into.

I am using Android Studio 2.1

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: I dont think that is related, but just in case, I am using the default location for the sdk path. but I dont see the live templates in any of the subfolders

Comment: Have you tried this path `<android-studio-path>\plugins\android\lib\templates\`?

Comment: Yes, and there are templates but they are "file" templates, the following is the folders under \templates: "activites", "eclipse", "gradle" "gradle-projects" and "other"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio. How export Live Template to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177276/android-studio-how-export-live-template-to-file)

Comment: The answer is already given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177276/android-studio-how-export-live-template-to-file

Answer (score 1):

Templates location for Windows:

`$ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH\plugins\android\lib\templates`

Answer (score 0):

On linux there is no templates directory by default, but if you create one in `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio[Version]/` and copy or link a live templates XML file, it will be used.

The directory and an XML file will also be created if you add a template via the settings interface.